# Pass a class as parameter

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to pass a class as a parameter but I do not know if it is possible.

```
class User {
    var $name;
}

class UserRepository {
  private $type;
  public function __construct(Class) {
     $this->type = Class;
  }

  public function getInstance() {
     return new $this->type;
  }
}

$obj = new UserRepository(User);
```

I am accepting suggestions on other ways to do it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just looking for a string:

```
class User {
    var $name;
}

class UserRepository {
  private $type;
  public function __construct($Class) {
                              ^^^^^^ this will be a string
     $this->type = $Class;
  }

  public function getInstance() {
     return new $this->type;
  }
}

$obj = new UserRepository('User');
                          ^^^^^^ send a string here

var_dump($obj->getInstance());
```

output:

> object(User)#2 (1) { ["name"]=> NULL }

[An example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9mXR0W).

Comment: @TafarelChicotti It works for your example, you would have to try it out yourself with namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Just instantiate the class and call that

```
$user = new User();
$obj = new UserRepository($user);
```

Another option (since `User` contains only variables) is to make the variable `static` and use that

```
class User {
    public static $name;
}
$obj = new UserRepository(User::$name);
```